# Taking User Information in Textbox and Adding it to Textbox in Another Page

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio-2013

Essentially I have a MainPage in my VS2013 project where I have Textboxes that ask for a From Location and To Location. Then there is a Route button which takes the user to a BING Map page. I want the user's input in the MainPage Textboxes to get added to the From and To boxes on the MapPage and then populate the route. I can populate the route from the MapPage already, but I cannot get the user input on the MainPage to get added to the From and To boxes on the MapPage.

This is the code to navigate to the MapPage:

```
    private void MapPage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Frame != null)
            {
                this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Views.MapPage));
            }
    }
```

This is the From and To boxes on the MapPage:

```
    <TextBlock Text="From:" FontSize="18"/>
    <TextBox Name="FromTbx" Width="220" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>

    <TextBlock Text="To:" FontSize="18"/>
    <TextBox Name="ToTbx" Width="220" Margin="33,10,0,10"/>
```

Comment: Web page? Client application? What are you doing here?

Comment: What technology? You need to give us more, what have you tried and what is going wrong.

Comment: It's a windows 8 app. C#/XAML in VS2013. I have been searching MSDN resources, stackoverflow, etc. for 3-4 hours on how to populate a textbox with data from another textbox on another page. I cannot figure it out. I tried a few things, but have had no luck. I tried adding this to my MainPage.xaml.cs but it didnt work:

Comment: private void MapPage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MapPage["From"] = From.Text;
            Server.Transfer("MapPage.xaml");
        }

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to create a model class to store the data, then bind the TextBox to a property on that model on both pages.

Then either store that object in a manager class or pass it to the new page.

On the model class, make sure to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Here is an example of data binding in XAML: http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2012/04/20/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-databinding-in-wpf-silverlight-and-wp7-part-two.html

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code to my MainPage.xaml.cs page:

```
    private void MapPage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Frame != null)
        {
            typeof(Views.MapPage).FromTbx = this.FromTxtBox.Text;
            typeof(Views.MapPage).ToTbx = this.ToTxtBox.Text; 
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Views.MapPage));
        }
    }
```

The intention with this code was that it would take the user's input from the textboxes and add them to the textboxes on the MapPage, but it is erroring out on the "FromTbx" and "ToTbx". The errors read: " 'System.Type' does not contain a definition for "FromTbx" accepting a first argument of type 'System.Type'could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) " (I am not missing either.)